# Does Swift NSAttributedString render JavaScript?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I noticed that `NSAttributedString` supports HTML rendering through `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`. Does `NSAttributedString` render JavaScript? I can't find any mention about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't render `javascript` with `NSAttributedString`. You are limited to `HTML` only! As you said that you haven't found anything mentioned about document, that is because `NSAttributedString` does not support `javascript`!